# ant failed when building project from source

Tags: ant, build

The below is the code in build.xml file throwing error. I googled and found some solutions like.. add ant contrib jar file to resolve the issue. Even after adding the jar file also facing same issue. Please see the below code.

```
<target name="copyHtdocs" depends="init">      
        <export srcUrl="${svn.htdocs.url}" revision="HEAD" destPath="${htdocs.dir}" />     
    <export srcUrl="${svn.htdocs.url}" destPath="${htdocs.dir}"/>
  </target>
```

Added Ant-contrib jar file:-

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${libs.dir}/ant-contrib-0.6.jar" />
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>
```

Error:-

```
C:\source\xxxx\xxxx\build.xml:156: Problem: failed to create task or type export
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Answer (score 0):

"export" is not a task that is part of the ant-contrib extension

- http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/

I suspect you're trying to export a git repo so I would suggest using this ANT task, instead:

- http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html#export